# Splitting a string array based on a word C#

Tags: c#, regex, split, string-matching

I have a string array in the following format:

```
      " Number 1 
        asdf asdfn asfm;lamf --- Information
        Number 2
        asdf asdfn asfm;lamf --- Information
        Number 3
        asdf asdfn asfm;lamf --- Information
      "
```

I have to get the whole string [] as separate string arrays:

```
string [] first = " Number 1 
                asdf asdfn asfm;lamf --- Information"


string [] second = " Number 2 
                asdf asdfn asfm;lamf --- Information"
```

How can I use Regex or Split so that I can use the keyword "Number" to split the string array. Please help me out!

Comment: can you give us the code you have tried?

Comment: Mystringarray.Split(new string[] { "Number" },                                                                               StringSplitOptions.None);

But Split doesn't work with string arrays.

Comment: Please tell us exactly what you're trying to achieve... Why would you use string arrays to store single strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a string with your original data:

```
        string testCase =  "Number 1 asdf asdfn asfm;lamf --- Information Number 2 asdf asdfn asfm;lamf --- Information Number 3 asdf asdfn asfm;lamf --- Information";

        string[] numbers = Regex.Split(testCase, "Number").Where(s => s.Trim() != "" && s != "Number").Select(x => "Number" + x).ToArray();
```

This will be the result: [image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem you'll run into with `string.Split()` is that it will remove your separator. A workaround could be to reinsert it.

```
string[] parts = originalString.Split(new[] { "Number" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(s => "Number" + s)
    .ToArray();
```

You'll still have to clean up the newlines...

Comment: Doesn't split take a char[] instead of a string?

Comment: @RodrigoSilva `Split` has many overloads but not the one in this answer.

Comment: I have a chunk of data. I need to separate them into smaller chunks. Each chunk starts with the word "Number". What should be my approach?